# How to stop running old screen on React Native Expo

Tags: react-native, expo, react-navigation

I use React Navigation for moving the screen.

I set stack screen like this:

```
<Stack.Screen name="camera" component={Opencamera} options={{headerShow: false}} />
<Stack.Screen name="previewpic" component={Previewpic} options={{headerShow: true}} />
```

so when I navigate `'camera'` to `'previewpic'` I can, but process in camera is running.  (This issue only occurs on `ios` devices.)

I need to moving to `previewpic` screen without `camera` screen running.
thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by "running"? What exactly happens?

Comment: Which `camera` library are you using? `expo camera` or `react-native-camera`?

Comment: yes expo camera

Comment: I make face detect in camera screen and I log it, when I moving to `previewpic` screen , terminal log code from camera screen all time

Comment: This seems to be an issue with the Expo Camera library itself and not related to react navigation. As unmount is called correctly when we go back from Screen B to Screen A. I'm still looking into how can we stop the Expo Camera upon navigation change

Answer (score 0):

Option 1:
Use the `unmountOnBlur` property, this will unmount the screen when the route changes;

```
<Stack.Screen name="camera" component={Opencamera} options={{headerShow: false, unmountOnBlur: true}} />
<Stack.Screen name="previewpic" component={Previewpic} options={{headerShow: true}} />
```

Option 2:
`useIsFocused` hook:

```
import { useIsFocused } from '@react-navigation/native';

....
// This hook returns `true` if the screen is focused, `false` otherwise
const isFocused = useIsFocused();

 return (isFocused &&  <Camera  />)
....
```